# Reduce the gap between cards - Ionic2

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

Can you tell me how to reduce the gap between cards? I have tried with `margin-bottom` but it is not working.

**Plunker :** [**Ionic2 Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HaNoHF)

**Note:** Please see the `home.html`

I would like it as:

[image]

**.sass**

```
page-event-schedule {
   .gray {
        background-color: #f5f5f0;
    }
    ion-card {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    ion-label {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the updated plnker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tT5cER?p=preview). I just deleted the `margin-top:-25px;` style rule hardcoded in the html of each `ion-item`, and added

```
ion-card {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ion-label {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: when I added it to `.sass` file,it is not working no.do you know why?please see the update.

Comment: when I use `!important` then it is working.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: if you want, instead of using important, you can try with something like `.ios, .md { page-event-schedule { ... } }` By doing that, your styles would have more priority than Ionic default styles.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)